# Artifactory query AQL with relative date

Tags: artifactory, artifactory-query-lang

I'm trying to query all artifacts that are older than 6 months old. I'm able to delete them if I hard code a date into my query.

```
{
  "files": [
    {
      "aql": {
        "items.find": {
          "repo": "foobar",
          "$or": [
            {
              "$and": [
                {
                  "modified": { "$lt": "2016-10-18T21:26:52.000Z"}
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

`jfrog rt del --spec /tmp/foo.spec --dry-run`

How can I do a query with a relative date? (e.g today - 6 months)

I'm going to put this into a cron job, and I'd rather not munge a spec file every time the cron job runs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AQL queries support relative time operators.

In this case, modify the query:

```
"modified": { "$lt": "2016-10-18T21:26:52.000Z"}
```

To:

```
"modified": { "$before": "6mo"}
```

See full documantation at: [AQL Relative Time Operators](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+Query+Language#ArtifactoryQueryLanguage-RelativeTimeOperators).